# paypal error Api: /smart/api/order/29B71296JP6358523/capture returned ack: permission_denied (Corr ID: -----)

Tags: javascript, paypal

I am using https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=ddd&currency=EUR
with frontEnd implementation, On Production I am getting this error.
paypal error Api: /smart/api/order/29B71296JP6358523/capture returned ack: permission_denied (Corr ID: -----)
I am not sure why and when it occurs as i am logging the caught error in OnError method.
Can someone help me out that why is it occuring...